# Redirecting to a page and loading image

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

on my server (Apache) I have a PHP page that loads images after making some log updates.
It's actually getting the requested filename through a GET variable and then using `fpassthru()`
to load the correct image.

I'm logging the headers sent by the user, and now I need to change the link format,

From: `http://domain.com/myfile.php?get=filename`

To: `http://domain.com/file/filename.jpg`

I need the the second URL to be parsed and redirected to myfile.php with the correct filename.

I know it can be done using htaccess but I want to preserve the headers that were sent.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rewrite rule should work:

```
RewriteRule ^file/([\w-]+)\.jpg$ myfile.php?get=$1 [L]
```

The headers are kept.

Comment: Does the request headers will be preserved?

Comment: That only makes Apache load myfile.php for the request matching that condition. There's no actual redirection, so the headers sent to the original URL will be available in myfile.php.